# Setting COM permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, com

Our little COM library is getting the dreaded 80004005 error on a customer's new computer. I recall this has to do with COM permissions, but for the life of me I can't find these any more on this machine. It's running Server 2008, can anyone point me to the right button?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Component Services ?

From there you can see COM+ and DCOM items and edit their properties, including some security settings.

Apart from that, my usual suggestion is to get [Process Monitor from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and run it on the computer, and see if you can find exactly what request is being denied